# How to Filter List<String,Object> Collection with java stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have

```
List<String, Person> generalList
```

as a list.
there is Customer object Under Person, 1 more list under Customer named Id

I want to filter this nested IdList under object but it is not working.

I tried to use flatMap but this code is not working

```
String s = generalList.stream()
.flatMap(a -> a.getCustomer().getIdList().stream())
.filter(b -> b.getValue().equals("1"))
.findFirst()
.orElse(null);
```

I expect the output as String or Customer object

Edit:
My original container is a map, I am filtering Map to List

Explanation.

```
Map<String, List<Person> container;

List<Person> list = container.get("A");

String s = list.stream()
.flatMap(a -> a.getCustomer().getIdList().stream())
.filter(b -> b.getValue().equals("1"))
.findFirst()
.orElse(null);
```

Here is the Person

```
public class Person
{
private Customer customer;

public Customer getCustomer ()
{
    return customer;
}
}
```

And Customer

```
public class Customer {
private Id[] idList;
/*getter setter*/
}
```

And Id

```
public class Id {
private String value;
/*getter setter*/
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `List<String, Object>` do you mean a `Map`?

Comment: list or map??b what you ,mean?

Comment: i guess you meant `List<Person>` where Person is POJO class

Comment: Instead of explaining in the text that it is a Map and not a List, why not put in that extra little bit of effort and update the code instead so it is correct and easier to understand for all of us who reads your question?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes it is my mistake. i explained it into edit

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i updated edit.

Comment: When edit your question, fix the wrong things instead of adding another contradicting part.

Answer (score 2):

You're possibly looking for a `map` operation as:

```
String s = list.stream()
        .flatMap(a -> a.getCustomer().getIdList().stream())
        .filter(b -> b.getValue().equals("1"))
        .findFirst()
        .map(Id::getValue) // map to the value of filtered Id
        .orElse(null);
```

which is equivalent of(just to clarify)

```
String valueToMatch = "1";
String s = list.stream()
        .flatMap(a -> a.getCustomer().getIdList().stream())
        .anyMatch(b -> b.getValue().equals(valueToMatch))
        ? valueToMatch : null;
```

Comment: .flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(a.getCustomer().getIdList())) is not working, the error is The method stream(T[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (List<Id>). getIdList returns List<Id>

Comment: @sakirow updated to adapt to `List<Id>` as a return type from `getIdList`

Answer (score 1):

*Update 2* This solution works directly on a list of Person objects:

```
String key = "1";
List<Person> list = container.get("A");
String filteredValue = list.stream()
    .flatMap(person -> Arrays.stream(person.getCustomer().getId())
    .filter(id -> id.getValue().equals(key)))
    .findFirst().get().getValue();
```

---

Old answer working with map
Since you are only interested in the values of your map you should stream on them and in the flatMap I not only got a stream on the `getId()` list but also filtered on them directly. So if I understood your code structure correctly this should work

```
String key = "1";

 String filteredValue =  map.values().stream()
     .flatMap(list -> list.stream()
     .flatMap(person -> Arrays.stream(person.getCustomer().getId())
     .filter(id -> id.getValue().equals("1"))))
     .findFirst().get().getValue();
```

*Updated to adjust for edited question*

Comment: I am converting map to List<Person>

Comment: @sakirow fixed so that I use list in my answer