# How to use stream to get an object from a list of lists

Tags: java, list, stream

My object is a collection of profiles that inside has a set of PerfilMenunode

```
public class Perfil {
    [...]
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PERFIL")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<PerfilMenunode> perfilMenunodes;
```

What I want to do is this function but only using stream

```
public PerfilMenunode darPerfilMenuNode(List<Perfil> perfiles) {
    PerfilMenunode perfilMenunode = null;
    for (Perfil perfil : perfiles) {
        perfilMenunode = perfil.getPerfilMenunodes().stream().filter(pm -> pm.getMenunode().getNombreCorto().equals(Constante.MENU_ADMINPERFIL_NOMBRECORTO)).findFirst().orElse(null);
        if(perfilMenunode!=null) {
            return perfilMenunode;
        }
    }
    return perfilMenunode;
}
```

Any solution?

Comment: @Naman OP doesnt want a list, reopened

Comment: Not sure why the history/audit is no more visible here. But would [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54528857/how-to-filter-liststring-object-collection-with-java-stream) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would give the following using `flatMap`

```java
public PerfilMenunode darPerfilMenuNode(List<Perfil> perfiles) {
    return perfiles.stream()
            .map(Perfil::getPerfilMenunodes)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .filter(pm -> pm.getMenunode()
                            .getNombreCorto()
                            .equals(Constante.MENU_ADMINPERFIL_NOMBRECORTO)
            )
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

But if you're using [java-16](/questions/tagged/java-16), you can use `Stream#mapMulti` instead of `flatMap`, it gives better performance, even more if your `perfilMenunodes` are small collections or empty collections

```java
public PerfilMenunode darPerfilMenuNode(List<Perfil> perfiles) {
    return perfiles.stream()
            .mapMulti((Perfil perfil, Consumer<PerfilMenunode> consumer) -> {
                perfil.getPerfilMenunodes().forEach(consumer::accept);
            })
            .filter(pm -> pm.getMenunode()
                            .getNombreCorto()
                            .equals(Constante.MENU_ADMINPERFIL_NOMBRECORTO)
            )
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can look like this:

```
public PerfilMenunode darPerfilMenuNode(List<Perfil> perfiles) {
   return perfiles.stream().flatMap(p -> p.getPerfilMenunodes().stream())
        .filter(pm -> pm.getMenunode().getNombreCorto().equals(Constante.MENU_ADMINPERFIL_NOMBRECORTO))
        .findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```